# Chaining response in Kohana fails with undefined property exception

Tags: php, kohana

I can't seem to chain some actions together, specifically this line of code:

```
$messages = Request::factory('messages/get_messages')->execute()->response;
```

When I play this in my browser, Kohana fails with the following warning.

> ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property: Response::$response

The full line of code for this reads...

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
  class Controller_Profile extends Controller_Application 
  {
    public function action_index()
    {
      $content = View::factory('profile/public')
        ->set('username', 'Test User')
        ->bind('messages', $messages);
      $messages = Request::factory('messages/get_messages')->execute()->response;
      $this->template->content = $content;
    }
  }
```

Since I've been going through [*Beginners Guide* by Jason D. Straughan](http://www.scribd.com/doc/67347262/Kohana), there have been a few little differences that I've been able to resolve but drawing a blank on this. Any pointers here would be appreciated.

This line of code is on page 81 of the book (jump to page 96 on the scribd viewer).

Comment: Which kohana version do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
$messages = Request::factory('messages/get_messages')->execute()->body();
```

The reason you get the `Notice error` is that the object `Response` (which is returned by `Request::factory(...)->execute()`) has no property called `$response` ( [Kohana Docs 3.1 | Response](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/Response) OR [Kohana Docs 3.2 | Response](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Response) ).